# Native lib in c for Android app on Galaxy A13 returns different value depending on build type (debug or release)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've an app that uses a native library to run some pretty simple calculations, mainly converting jbyteArray into char *, doing some vector calculations, and returning the result back into jbyteArray

The lib is written in c, and on most smartphones tested, the same input parameters yield the same results, whether it's a debug or release build.

But on a particular smartphone, namely a Samsung's Galaxy A13 on Android 12, with the same input parameters, the lib returns a different value.

This is totally unexpected.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue ?
Why would a lib on a release build yields a value different than using a debug build ?

Comment: Generally when that happens its due to different compile flags between the two builds.  Particularly looking at ones that would change the optimization settings o the compiler or change defines for the preprocessor.  But without code its hard to actually help here.

Comment: The native c code is pretty simple, mainly converting jbyteArray into char *, doing some vector calculations, and returning the result back into jbyteArray.  I noticed one thing in api-level.h though, there is no constant defined for api level 31, the last constant is __ANDROID_API_R__ 30 Could it have an impact ?